# Show volume slider when pressing "Volume +"/"Volume -" buttons on keyboard

Tags: windows-7, windows

Windows 8 and above has a nice slider showing up in the top left corber of the screen wherever you change the system volume via keyboard's  "Volume +"/"Volume -" buttons. It allows you to have avisual confirmation of how loud or quiet is the new system volume.

I doubt that Windows 7 has such kind of onscreen indicator as well. So, the simplest solution seems to have an option that standard Windows 7 volume slider (the one that popping when you click the speaker icon in the system tray) would show up instead.

I'm not a fan of installing of any 3rd party app just for this tiny feature.

So, how can we make standard Windows 7 volume slider to show up when pressing "Volume +"/"Volume -" buttons on keyboard?

Comment: You can do that inn VLC or in YouTube video with Ctrl and +/-

Comment: Would it change the system volume?

Comment: Try [Is There Keyboard Shortcut For Volume Control?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/is-there-keyboard-shortcut-for-volume-control/54609d6e-ce9d-4866-89c0-eb6a86926237?auth=1)

Comment: @JosefZ: This seems to be setting some shortcut, not using the  "Volume +"/"Volume -" buttons...